# Laravel 5 form field name != database column name

Tags: database, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a new project with Laravel 5. But I have a problem.
In my `<form>`, I have a field with `name="tata"`, but in my database, the destination column is `toto`.

So, how can I store the value from field `tata` into my column `toto` ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the value "manually", that would be the simplest solution:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->toto = $request->input('tata');
$model->save();
```

Comment: Yes I found this way in same time ... sorry I'm so begginer and stupid ^^